# How to draw an ellipse or ellipsoid between two points in java swing

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I have two point coordinates. One start point and one end point.

I want to draw an ellipse between these two points in a Java Swing application.

How can i do this using Graphics 2d or 3d.

```
final Point p1 = new Point(17, 58);
   final Point p2 = new Point(324, 312);
final Ellipse2D.Double el = new Ellipse2D.Double(p1.x > p2.x ? p2.x : p1.x, 
                            p1.y > p2.y ? p2.y : p1.y,
                            60,
                            Math.abs(p1.y - p2.y));
```

height is 60 here t can be vary.

Here  the x and the y coordinates are the starting point coordinates

How can I use one variable as fixed end point coordinate, to draw my ellipse?

please see the image below [image]

Answer (score 3):

For custom paintings you need to use `paintComponent()` method of `JComponent`, for example `JPanel`. [Read more about that.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Seems you are looking for something like next:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.beans.Transient;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test extends JFrame{

    public Test(){
        init();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        final Point p1 = new Point(210, 280);
        final Point p2 = new Point(160, 190);
        final Ellipse2D.Double el = new Ellipse2D.Double(p1.x > p2.x ? p2.x : p1.x, 
                            p1.y > p2.y ? p2.y : p1.y,
                            Math.abs(p1.x - p2.x),
                            Math.abs(p1.y - p2.y));

        JPanel p = new JPanel(){
            protected void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.draw(el);
                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2d.drawString("P1", p1.x, p1.y);
                g2d.drawString("P2", p2.x, p2.y);
            };

            @Override
            @Transient
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(p1.x+p2.x+10,p1.y+p2.y+10);
            }
        };

        add(p);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hiiii @alex2410  I have edited my code according to code shared by you still having problem i have edited my questions also.

Comment: In that case you need to calculate width and height according to diagonal of rectangle. And then withe help of  `g2d.rotate()` rotate graphics before `g2d.draw(el);`.